# function overloading ambiguity in c++

Tags: c++, overloading

I have two functions with the signatures as below.

```
void overloading(int, int)
```

and

```
void overloading(int, A *ptr, int)
```

where A is a class.

When I am compiling in gcc 3.4. My main function has the following call.

```
A *pointer = new A();

overloading(10, pointer,20);
```

I get an error which says

```
"Invalid conversion from A * to int"
```

Am I doing something wrong or the compiler is not able to identify the correct overloaded function?

Comment: Post real code please - this should work. Your problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: Can you post a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem? BTW that is a seriously old compiler, people might struggle to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any chance the second definition prototype is not being included in the code that claims improper params?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that at the location you may the call to `overloading` you haven't declared the three parameter version of the function so the compiler only sees the `(int, int)` version. You can even prove this by pre-processing the source file (for example `g++ -E`).

Just make sure to include all the needed headers in your main file.

Comment: +1 No surprise that I support this answer, given my comment in the general section. I would highly suspect this is accurate.